# IQueryable - Statement(s) could not be prepared

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a huge dataset that I'm trying to execute but I'm experiencing the following error;

```
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

**Stack Trace**

```
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDataReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at SalesForceReportSVC.Controllers.SalesForceDataLoaderController.<GetSDL>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\SalesForceReportSVC\SalesForceReportSVC\Controllers\SalesForceDataLoaderController.cs:line 60
```

The exception is thrown at the following statement

```
IQueryable<SalesForceProductionReportDto> dLProductions = this.repo_.salesforceLoader.FindAll();

IEnumerable<SalesForceProductionReportDto> reportDtos = dLProductions.ToList();
```

**Repository**

```
public IQueryable<SalesForceProductionReportDto> FindAll()
{
    return this.salesForceReport.Set<SalesForceProductionReportDto>().AsNoTracking();
}
```

**Context**

```
private void ConfigureAPIIntegrations(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.APIdb, opt => opt.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).TotalSeconds));
     optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors();
}
```

I want the `ToList` to implement and load data from the database.

**EDIT**

Even a simple Linq Query like this;

```
List<SalesForceProductionReportDto> salesForces = this.salesForceReport.productionReports.Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Takes a lot of time to execute yet I can execute a `SELECT` statement for 15000 plus records in less than 1 sec.

**EDIT 2**

I'm selecting from a view as shown in `Context`

```
public virtual DbSet<SalesForceProductionReportDto> productionReports { get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Entity<SalesForceProductionReportDto>().HasNoKey() .ToView("DailyProductionReport_Vw");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

 }
```

Comment: Why `.Select(x => x)`?

Comment: Well, I want the Select statement to execute in SQL rather than in memory so I specified it at there..  I am trying to make sure that I don't run any Linq in memory

Comment: That's not what that does. Use Select only if you want a result set that isn't just your database objects.

Comment: OK, I'll fix this...

Comment: How about the bug which fails to convert IQueryable to List?

Comment: Check the SQL query that is generated. That contains some error.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't received a reason as to why it's not working.

I found a walk around to the above problem, using `FromSqlRaw`

So the following line is working;

```
List<SalesForceProductionReportDto> salesForces = this.salesForceReport.Set<SalesForceProductionReportDto>().FromSqlRaw<SalesForceProductionReportDto>("SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductionData_Vw;").ToList();
```